# Convexity of expectation

Tags: calculus, integration, convex-analysis, gaussian-integral, expected-value

Given some function $f$, how could I find out what properties of $f$ make
$$F(q) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\sqrt{q} x) e^{-x^2/2} dx$$
either convex or concave?

I have some functions $f$ for which I can actually analytically find $F$ and do some basic analysis to find out whether it is convex or not, but for others, e.g. $f(x) = \tanh(x)^2$, it seems to be impossible.

I have tried to compute first and second derivatives of $F$, but that does not seem to help (me) much:
$$\begin{align}
  F'(q) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} f''(\sqrt{q} x) e^{-x^2/2} dx \\
  F''(q) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4} f^{(4)}(\sqrt{q} x) e^{-x^2/2} dx \\
\end{align}$$

Would anybody be able to give me a hint as to how I could find for some $f$, whether $F$ is convex or concave?

PS: I'm a computer scientists, so please forgive me if I don't understand continuous maths.

Comment: One sufficient condition is if the function is Absolutely Monotone. I doubt that there is a general characterization of functions for which that integral is nonnegative.

Comment: @MikeHawk I do not really need a general characterization. But some generalization would definitely be useful. E.g. $\tanh$ is odd, increasing and bounded, does this tell me anything about the convexity of $F$?

Comment: Like I mentioned, being absolutely monotone is one such generalization, https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolutely_monotonic_function. Are you specifically interested in tanh, or do you just want to find *a* function making F convex?

Comment: @MikeHawk I am interested in checking if $F$ is convex for a given $f$, $\tanh$ is one such $f$, but I have other functions as well. If anybody could give me an idea how I can show that for $\tanh$ $F$ is concave, I might be able to move forward from there...

Comment: These derivatives have not been properly computed.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Where would my mistake be? I used that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) x e^{-x^2/2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx$$ to simplify the expressions.

Comment: Yes, forgive me, you are right. I'm sorry. Anyway: that expression for the second derivative gives you a condition in terms of the Fourier transform of $f$, is that interesting for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is useful to you, but the expression 
$$
F''(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^{(4)}(\sqrt q x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx$$ 
can be evaluated in terms of Fourier transforms by means of the following version of the [Plancherel identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem);
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\overline{g(x)}\, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(k)\overline{\hat{g}(k)}\, dk.$$
Here 
$$
\hat{f}(k):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ikx}\, dx.$$

To begin with the evaluation we note that 
$$
\widehat{f^{(4)}}(k)=k^4\hat{f}(k), 
$$
as you can see by integrating by parts in the definition of $\hat{f}$. Moreover, applying the general scaling property
$$
\widehat{g(x/q)}(k)=q\hat{g}(qk)
$$
we see that 
$$
\widehat{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2q}}}=Ce^{-q\frac{k^2}{2}}.$$
Here and in the following $C$ denotes an irrelevant positive constant. Using the considerations above, we have that 
$$
F''(q)=C\int_{-\infty}^\infty k^4 e^{-q\frac{k^2}{2}}\hat{f}(k)\, dk.$$ 
In particular, $F$ will be convex (concave) if $\hat{f}$ is nonnegative (nonpositive).

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether I understand this. I figured out that $\hat{f^{(4)}}(k) = C_0 k^4 \hat{f}(k)$ and $\hat{e^{-\cdot^2/2}}(k) = C_1 e^{-k^2/2}$, but I am not quite sure why we can use Plancherel's identity (there's no squares) and how $q$ got in the exponent there...

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote little detail. I will edit this answer later to add some more to it.

Comment: @MrTsjolder: I added some detail, I hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: Now I understand it. It's interesting, but unfortunately, it does not seem to be possible to compute the fourier transforms for the functions I'm working with, e.g. $\tanh(x)^2$

Comment: You do not need the full expression of the Fourier transform, but only its positivity properties; see here, it might help you: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194107/conditions-for-positivity-of-fourier-transform SUMMARY: The easy criterion for positiveness of the Fourier transform is that $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $f$ is decreasing on $[0, \infty)$. This is unfortunately not the case of $\tanh^2(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I just found the cited paper myself as well. For $\tanh^2(x)$, I would need negativity of the Fourier transform (numerical approximations make believe that $F$ be concave). I will dig into it!

Comment: There are some technical difficulties, because $\tanh^2$ is not integrable and as such the integral defining its Fourier transform is not absolutely convergent. Nonetheless, I think that an appropriate version of the negativity of its Fourier transform is true, because it is even and increasing. It might be easier to directly show that $\int f^{(4)}(q x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\le 0$, though, using the explicit expression of $f^{(4)}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83979/discussion-between-mr-tsjolder-and-giuseppe-negro).

Comment: what if $\hat{f}(k)$ is complex, rather than real?

Comment: Am I correct to claim that if the imaginary part of $\hat{f}(k)$ is odd, it suffices that the real part of $\hat{f}(k)$ is positive/negative?

Comment: Well, f is real, so its Fourier transform has the property that if you evaluate it at $-k$ you get its conjugate. Using this it should be true that the imaginary part of that integral vanishes. If it is not true, then my answer is wrong! Indeed, that integral is real. (sorry for the hasty answer, I'm on my phone while traveling)